# Toy Program - Using GDB to bypass a C-function

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm doing an exercise in GDB using the C programming language, which is way to help developers debug their coding, but can't seem to understand the direction to take.

All I know is that the toy program asks for a password, and the eventual exercise destination is that GDB is supposed to allow the finding of vulnerabilities and thus bypass the checking of the password. That's really all I'm given, so any code would be as confusing as it is to me as it is to the reader. So basically, I'm asking for a set of steps more experienced people would attempt.

I have dumped through objdump and found a very large dump. I've found the main func but afterwards just a lot of library functions with the very cryptic hex and assembly code.
Is there a different heuristic I should be taking? I am not too familiar with stacks, so maybe something with that? I know I can set breakpoints but would not know what function to look for to start with. When the program runs, it says "Please input password", I type a random password, and the toy program says "Password is incorrect!". Somewhere in between that I need to intercept something, but that is beyond me.

Thanks for the assistance. You'd be making a lifelong scholar very happy.

Comment: Okay !!! so where is the code  ??

Comment: I don't think I have access to the code. All it is is a precompiled file called 'login', which I'm dissecting through 'gdb login' in terminal. Is there any way I can provide the code through this?

Comment: If this is "use the C programming language", does that mean that you have the source code?

Comment: Yes, I do. How should I transfer it? It is just a c program called login (I'm running in a VM, as I am told to protect my computer). It is here: http://wikisend.com/download/674666/ (rated green by Web of Trust.

Comment: you need the symbols, else this is an asm question. transfer the program using copy/paste...

Comment: I don't know if the code is accessible? How would I open the file that is already compiled from a c file?

Comment: Assuming it is just an assembly language question of pinpointing where to place breakpoints, what would you do? File is uploaded above - although I recognize it is a file and ensure it is okay to download.

Comment: @JohnHelper If you have the source code (a file named `login.c`), then that is a plain text file. If all you have is the runnable program ("the binary") then you *don't* have the source code.

Comment: @JohnHelper it looks like all you have is an executable binary -> adjusted tags. **If** you have some C source-files as well and/or some debugging symbols for `gdb`, you might re-add the C tag.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification. So, would all programs doing the same thing from different programming languages be reduced to roughly to same binary? I just have this file - is this sufficient to fulfill that task that I entertained, i.e. to bypass the (supposedly purposely weak) pass function?

Comment: You need disassembler + debugger like ollydbg for what you are trying to do

Comment: I'll look into those. Once I install them, what type of heuristic would I be taking?

Comment: Okay I put many characters into the password input field and created a segmentation fault, and then used backtrace to find 0x08048324 in main(), as some of the pages I perused have hinted me toward. Is this getting warmer, as we say?